# form of list definition displays only 'Title'

Tags: list, list-form

I develop a ListTemplate for a Site. The Schema.xml contains already my custom content type, fields and a view. So far it works, but the default Forms only display the title of the elements. I read various guides and walkthroughs but the behavior is always the same. Nothing happens. The used ContentType seems to be correct, because if I add the forms per SharePointDesigner the forms are working correctly (but this solution can't be used, because of project requirements). What did I do wrong?

Here comes the snippets from the Schema.xml:

```
<Fields>
      <FieldRef ID="30D9991A-34F3-455F-AE22-31929F68D797" Name="Attachments" 
                Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
  <Field Name="Title" StaticName="Title" DisplayName="Titel" Type="Text" FromBaseType="TRUE"
         ID="21A9B1CC-CBEA-4D8A-9AEF-0F1BD7F1BE97"
         Required="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
  <Field Name="LastSendAt" StaticName="LastSendAt" DisplayName="Zuletzt versendet am" Type="DateTime"
         ID="EF7457B6-9B1E-4EC5-BDEA-25E7DC261F1E"
         Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
  <Field Name="SendCount" StaticName="SendCount" DisplayName="Anzahl Gesendet" Type="Number"
         ID="5D2E3FFC-C4FA-40CB-8DBC-57C9BFF145A4" Min="0" Decimals="0"
         Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" >
    <Default>0</Default>
  </Field>
  <Field Name="ShowItem" StaticName="ShowItem" DisplayName="Anzeigen" Type="URL"
         ID="F67BF167-FD90-42E9-88F8-65BCBF107D21"
         Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" />
  <Field Name="SendAgain" StaticName="SendAgain" DisplayName="Erneut senden" Type="URL"
         ID="C90B89D2-613A-4075-A2F3-5C6359363589"
         Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" />
</Fields>
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentType ID="0x0100E2F56874BC38480481DA64E39727CAC0"
               Name="NewsletterContentType"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="Custom Content Type for Newsletter"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0" >
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="21A9B1CC-CBEA-4D8A-9AEF-0F1BD7F1BE97" Name="Title"  
                Required="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="EF7457B6-9B1E-4EC5-BDEA-25E7DC261F1E" Name="LastSendAt" 
                Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="5D2E3FFC-C4FA-40CB-8DBC-57C9BFF145A4" Name="SendCount" 
                Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="F67BF167-FD90-42E9-88F8-65BCBF107D21" Name="ShowItem" 
                Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE"  />
      <FieldRef ID="C90B89D2-613A-4075-A2F3-5C6359363589" Name="SendAgain" 
                Required="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</ContentTypes>
<Views>
  <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" ReadOnly="FALSE" ContentTypeID="0x0100E2F56874-BC38-4804-81DA-64E39727CAC0" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="Newsletteransicht" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments" ID="30D9991A-34F3-455F-AE22-31929F68D797" ></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Title" ID="21A9B1CC-CBEA-4D8A-9AEF-0F1BD7F1BE97" ></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LastSendAt" ID="EF7457B6-9B1E-4EC5-BDEA-25E7DC261F1E" ></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="SendCount" ID="5D2E3FFC-C4FA-40CB-8DBC-57C9BFF145A4" ></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="ShowItem" ID="F67BF167-FD90-42E9-88F8-65BCBF107D21"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="SendAgain" ID="C90B89D2-613A-4075-A2F3-5C6359363589"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="LastSendAt" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
</Views>
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

Comment: Feel like including the `<Views>` section?

Comment: What happens if you also add in the ID attribute into the FieldRefs in the ViewFields?

Comment: Long shot - but have you tried adding the FieldRefs in the ViewFields in the form <FieldRef Name="ShowItem" ID="..." />? Rather than an open close? I know it shouldn't make a difference - but I've found that with CAML, sometimes it does.

Comment: I also tried this, but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround found. At the moment I defined the ContentType in the ListDefinition. When I sourced it out, to an separate ContentType and referenced this in my View it works.